# Mongodb result and python result difference

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

when I query in studio3t, I get a response in .net uuid type, and when I query in python, I get UUID Version=1. How can I translate this output in python?

mongo response;
[image]

pyton response;

```
{'_id': UUID('0fc97e3a-8f0c-be4f-a5dc-b166af761afd'), 'Version': 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is the same, just the representation is different. See https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/uuid.rst

> The Java, C#, and Python drivers natively support platform types for
> UUID, all of which by default encode them to and decode them from BSON
> binary subtype 3. However, each encode the bytes in a different order
> from the others. To improve interoperability, BSON binary subtype 4
> was introduced and defined the byte order according to RFC 4122, and a
> mechanism to configure each driver to encode UUIDs this way was added
> to each driver. The legacy representation remained as the default for
> each driver.
>
> This specification moves MongoDB drivers further towards the standard
> UUID representation by requiring an application relying on native UUID
> support to explicitly specify the representation it requires.
>
> Drivers that support native UUID types will additionally create
> helpers on their BsonBinary class that will aid in conversion to and
> from the platform native UUID type.

Comment: how can i convert the data to mongo's data pls help me

Comment: *The data is the same, just the representation is different.* I suggest you edit your question to make it clear what you are trying to achieve.